# Camera position not inside Skybox three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a 3D solar system project that involves a rocket rotation around a planet. I tried following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fJgVyq0OYo) to create a skybox for my planets to exist within. Although there are no errors being displayed and I know the skybox is being created, it is nowhere near my planets and rocket and I'm unsure how to make my camera start in the center of the scene. My code is as follows,

```js
        // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
        $(function() {
            
            var stats = initStats();

            // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            // create a render and set the size
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            
            window.addEventListener('resize', function()
        {
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
           
        } );
        
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        
        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000,10000,10000);
        var cubeMaterials = 
        [
           new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/purplenebula_ft.png"), side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
           new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/purplenebula_bk.png"), side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
           new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/purplenebula_up.png"), side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
           new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/purplenebula_dn.png"), side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
           new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/purplenebula_rt.png"), side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
           new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/purplenebula_lf.png"), side: THREE.DoubleSide})
            
        ];
        
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cubeMaterials);
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, cubeMaterial);
        scene.add(cube);
        
        
        // create the object group that contains all the sub-shapes
        var rocketGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
        scene.add(rocketGroup);
        //display grid
        //scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(100,10));
        
        var rocketMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xEEEEEE});
        var hingeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFD1414});
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var rocketAntennaOne = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 1, 1, 5);   
        var rocketAntennaOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaOne, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());            
        var rocketAntennaTwo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1, 1.5, 0.5, 5 );            
        var rocketAntennaTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaTwo, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketAntennaThree = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1.5, 2, 0.5, 5 );
        var rocketAntennaThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( rocketAntennaThree,hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var rocketBodyOne = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 2, 4, 3, 5 );   
        var rocketBodyOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyOne,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyTwo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 4, 5.5, 3, 5 );   
        var rocketBodyTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyTwo,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyThree = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5.5, 7, 3, 5 );   
        var rocketBodyThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyThree,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyFour = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 7, 7.5, 3, 5 );   
        var rocketBodyFourMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyFour,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyFive = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 7.5, 8, 3.5, 5 );   
        var rocketBodyFiveMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyFive,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodySix = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 8, 8, 5, 5 );   
        var rocketBodySixMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodySix,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodySeven = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 8, 7.5, 3.5, 5 );   
        var rocketBodySevenMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodySeven,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyEight = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 7.5, 7, 3.5, 5 ); 
        var rocketBodyEightMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyEight,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyNine = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 7, 6.5, 3, 5 ); 
        var rocketBodyNineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyNine,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        var rocketBodyTen = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 6.5, 6, 3, 5 ); 
        var rocketBodyTenMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyTen,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
        var rocketBodyUpper = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 3.5, 4, 3.5, 5 );
        var rocketBodyUpperMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyUpper,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());            
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
        var rocketBodyLower = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 2.75, 3, 2.5, 5 );
        var rocketBodyLowerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyLower,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        //var rocketWindow = new THREE.RingGeometry(5,6,30);
        //var rocketWindowMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketWindow,hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;                
        var RocketFinOne = new THREE.Shape();        
        RocketFinOne.moveTo( x + 0, y + 0 );
        RocketFinOne.lineTo( x + 0, y + 16);
        RocketFinOne.lineTo( x + 7, y + 20);
        RocketFinOne.lineTo( x + 7, y + 15);
        RocketFinOne.lineTo( x + 2.5, y + 13);        
        var extrudeSettings = {amount: 0.01, bevelEnabled:true, bevelSegments:2,steps:2,bevelSize:1,bevelThickness:1};        
        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( RocketFinOne,extrudeSettings );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFD1414 } );
        var rocketFinOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
        var RocketFinTwo = new THREE.Shape();        
        RocketFinTwo.moveTo( x + 0, y + 0 );
        RocketFinTwo.lineTo( x + 0, y + 16);
        RocketFinTwo.lineTo( x + 7, y + 20);
        RocketFinTwo.lineTo( x + 7, y + 15);
        RocketFinTwo.lineTo( x + 2.5, y + 13);        
        var extrudeSettings = {amount: 0.01, bevelEnabled:true, bevelSegments:2,steps:2,bevelSize:1,bevelThickness:1};        
        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( RocketFinTwo,extrudeSettings );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFD1414 } );
        var rocketFinTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
        var RocketFinThree = new THREE.Shape();        
        RocketFinThree.moveTo( x + 0, y + 0 );
        RocketFinThree.lineTo( x + 0, y + 16);
        RocketFinThree.lineTo( x + 7, y + 20);
        RocketFinThree.lineTo( x + 7, y + 15);
        RocketFinThree.lineTo( x + 2.5, y + 13);        
        var extrudeSettings = {amount: 0.01, bevelEnabled:true, bevelSegments:2,steps:2,bevelSize:1,bevelThickness:1};        
        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( RocketFinThree,extrudeSettings );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFD1414 } );
        var rocketFinThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
        var RocketFinFour = new THREE.Shape();        
        RocketFinFour.moveTo( x + 0, y + 0 );
        RocketFinFour.lineTo( x + 0, y + 16);
        RocketFinFour.lineTo( x + 7, y + 20);
        RocketFinFour.lineTo( x + 7, y + 15);
        RocketFinFour.lineTo( x + 2.5, y + 13);        
        var extrudeSettings = {amount: 0.01, bevelEnabled:true, bevelSegments:2,steps:2,bevelSize:1,bevelThickness:1};        
        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( RocketFinFour,extrudeSettings );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFD1414 } );
        var rocketFinFourMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var planetEarth = createPlanetEarthMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 400, 400));
    var planetMoon = createMoonMesh (new THREE.SphereGeometry (40,100,100));
    var planetSun = createSunMesh (new THREE.SphereGeometry (150,100,100));
            // add the sphere to the scene
            
    
  
        
  
        scene.add(planetEarth);
        scene.add(planetMoon);
        scene.add(planetSun);
        
        //scene.add(EarthMesh);
        //////////////////////////////////////
        scene.add(rocketAntennaOneMesh);
        scene.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
        scene.add(rocketAntennaThreeMesh);
        /////////////////////////////////////
        scene.add(rocketBodyOneMesh);
        scene.add(rocketBodyTwoMesh);  
        scene.add(rocketBodyThreeMesh);  
        scene.add(rocketBodyFourMesh);  
        scene.add(rocketBodyFiveMesh);  
        scene.add(rocketBodySixMesh);
        scene.add(rocketBodySevenMesh);  
        scene.add(rocketBodyEightMesh);
        scene.add(rocketBodyNineMesh);  
        scene.add(rocketBodyTenMesh);
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        scene.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
        scene.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        //scene.add(rocketWindowMesh);
        //////////////////////////////////////
        scene.add( rocketFinOneMesh );
        scene.add( rocketFinTwoMesh );
        scene.add( rocketFinThreeMesh );
        scene.add( rocketFinFourMesh );
        
        rocketGroup.position.y = 100;
        
        planetEarth.position.y=-100;
        planetMoon.position.x=-100;
        planetSun.position.x=200;
        //Specify the position of the rocket cone
        rocketAntennaOneMesh.position.y = 52.05;
        rocketAntennaTwoMesh.position.y = 51.3;
        rocketAntennaThreeMesh.position.y = 50.8;
        rocketBodyOneMesh.position.y = 49.1;
        rocketBodyTwoMesh.position.y = 46.1;
        rocketBodyThreeMesh.position.y = 43.1;
        rocketBodyFourMesh.position.y = 40.1;
        rocketBodyFiveMesh.position.y = 36.9;
        rocketBodySixMesh.position.y = 32.7;
        rocketBodySevenMesh.position.y = 28.5;
        rocketBodyEightMesh.position.y = 25.2;
        rocketBodyNineMesh.position.y = 22;
        rocketBodyTenMesh.position.y = 19;            
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
        rocketBodyUpperMesh.position.y = 16;
        rocketBodyLowerMesh.position.y = 14;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //rocketWindowMesh.position.y = 100;
        //rocketwindowMesh.position.x = -20;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        rocketFinOneMesh.position.x=-7;
        rocketFinOneMesh.position.y=3;
        rocketFinOneMesh.rotation.z = 0.1 * Math.PI;
        
        rocketFinTwoMesh.position.x=6   ;
        rocketFinTwoMesh.position.y=3;
        rocketFinTwoMesh.rotation.z = 0.1 * Math.PI;
        rocketFinTwoMesh.rotation.y = 1 * Math.PI;
        
        rocketFinThreeMesh.position.x=0;
        rocketFinThreeMesh.position.y=3;
        rocketFinThreeMesh.position.z = 7;
        rocketFinThreeMesh.rotation.z = 0.1 * Math.PI;
        rocketFinThreeMesh.rotation.y = 0.5 * Math.PI;
        
        
        rocketFinFourMesh.position.x=0;
        rocketFinFourMesh.position.y=3;
        rocketFinFourMesh.position.z = -6;
        rocketFinFourMesh.rotation.z = 0.1 * Math.PI;
        rocketFinFourMesh.rotation.y = 1.5 * Math.PI;
        
        
        //Add the rocketCone to the lowpolyRocket group
        rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaOneMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaThreeMesh);
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyOneMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyTwoMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyThreeMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyFourMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyFiveMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodySixMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodySevenMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyEightMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyNineMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyTenMesh);
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyLowerMesh);
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        rocketGroup.add(rocketFinOneMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketFinTwoMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketFinThreeMesh);
        rocketGroup.add(rocketFinFourMesh);
        

            
            //position and point the camera to the center of the scene
            camera.position.x = -400;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            camera.position.z = 3;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // add subtle ambient lighting
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            // add spotlight for the shadows
            var spotLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
            spotLight.position.set(-200, 50, 150);
            spotLight.castShadow = true;
            scene.add(spotLight);

            // add the output of the renderer to the html element
            $("#WebGL-output").append(renderer.domElement);

            var controls = new function() {
                
                this.EarthMoonRotationSpeed = 1.0;
                this.EarthMoonRotationSpeed = 1.0;
            };
            
            
            
            
            
            var gui = new dat.GUI();
            gui.add(controls, 'EarthMoonRotationSpeed', 0, 5);

            // call the render function
            var angle = 0;
            render();

            function render() {
                stats.update();
                
                angle += 0.002 * controls.EarthMoonRotationSpeed;
                planetEarth.rotation.y = angle;
                
                angle += 0.002 * controls.EarthMoonRotationSpeed;
                planetMoon.rotation.y = angle;
                
                
                
                // render using requestAnimationFrame
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            
                function createPlanetEarthMesh(geom) {
                var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var planetEarthTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/Earth.png");
                var normalEarthTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/EarthNormal.png");

                var planetEarthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: planetEarthTexture, bumpMap: normalEarthTexture});

                // create a multimaterial
                var planetEarthMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [planetEarthMaterial]);

                return planetEarthMesh;
            }
            
            function createMoonMesh(geom) {
                var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var planetMoonTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/moon.jpg");
                var normalMoonTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/moonbump.jpg");

                var planetMoonMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: planetMoonTexture, bumpMap: normalMoonTexture});

                // create a multimaterial
                var planetMoonMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [planetMoonMaterial]);

                return planetMoonMesh;
            }
            
            function createSunMesh(geom) {
                var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var planetSunTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/sun.jpg");
                //var normalSunTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/moonbump.jpg");

                var planetSunMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: planetSunTexture});
                //bumpMap: normalMoonTexture

                // create a multimaterial
                var planetSunMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [planetSunMaterial]);

                return planetSunMesh;
            }

            function initStats() {

                var stats = new Stats();

                stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

                // Align top-left
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

                $("#Stats-output").append(stats.domElement);

                return stats;
            }
        });
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/utils/SceneUtils.js"></script>
```

The snippet won't display because "SceneUtils.js" don't seem to work. The project is made in an older version of three.js I'm assuming (unsure how to check the version) since I had to create this project with a default-project. (It is part of an assignment and we were asked to use that version of three.js). When I run the project on my computer it works though since I have that version.

Is there anyway I can link the script properly so you may all view my project and help?

---------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

Okay, so I realized that the error might be to do with my rendering? it seems like the skybox i was making was too big, but when i'd make it much smaller, it would view. Although if I'd look at certain angles, part of the cube with vanish as if it's not being rendered.

As you can see from this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH36C.jpg

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once. You want help with the skybox, and the position of your camera, and how to import SceneUtils... StackOverflow was made to answer one issue per question. Has your class instructor taught you how to use the browser console? If you open the console in JSFiddle, you'll see a clear error: `THREE.SceneUtils has been moved to /examples/js/utils/SceneUtils.js`. Just add this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/utils/SceneUtils.js"></script>` and your SceneUtils will be available in the JSFiddle.

Comment: @Marquizzo well my main question was about the skybox, I was trying to get the jsfiddle to work so you guys can understand my error better

Comment: @Marquizzo I've made the skybox but my camera doesn't actually start inside it, and it doesn't function the way it should do

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-backgrounds.html) useful

Comment: @gman I'm not too sure how to apply that to mine? I've made the css part, but the second webglrenderer part is confusing me since i already have a webglrenderer

Comment: @Marquizzo I've added an update to the post  too

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "second WebGLRenderer". There is no second WebGLRenderer in the article I linked to. Instead there is a shader based skybox which uses a cubemap which solves the issues you're having.

Comment: @gman I meant that, I already have a WebGLRenderer property, and the link you said says to make one too, I wasn't too sure how to merge those bits of code together if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edit, it seems the problem is your [camera frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) settings. This specifies how far objects can be away from the camera and still be rendered. Some parts of your sky box aren't within the far viewing plane, so are being cut off, resulting in the white background of your scene appearing. To fix this, increase your far frustum to above 1000 when you create your camera:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
```

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! :D I can navigate across my scene within the cube freely now without it ever cutting off. Thank you so much for this suggestion, the Skybox functions perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty bad tutorial that's asking you to do a lot of unnecessary work. Three.js already comes with a built-in and easier way to create a skybox: the [CubeTextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/CubeTextureLoader):

```
    var r = "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/Park3Med/";

    var urls = [
        r + "px.jpg", 
        r + "nx.jpg",
        r + "py.jpg", 
        r + "ny.jpg",
        r + "pz.jpg", 
        r + "nz.jpg"
    ];

    var textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
    scene.background = textureCube;
```

The code above was taken directly from [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction)

With this method, you don't have to worry about your camera's position at all; it'll always be in the center of the cube, no matter how far your camera moves in any direction.

Comment: What exactly is the link in the variable r? I get a page 404, so I'm unsure how to relate it to mine, but the rest looks very straight forward

Comment: ahh, I assumed it'll be the initial part of the url to the images so I made mine as follows "var r = "../assets/textures/skybox/ame_nebula/";" and then did       "r + "purplenebula_ft.png"" etc. But no skybox is created.

Comment: The link in the variable is the folder in which the images are stored, so when you add `px.png` to the end of the URL, then it'll take you [directly to the image](https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/Park3Med/px.jpg). Have you checked your dev tools in the console or network tab? If not, do a quick search on how to open the console on your browser to see if the nebula .pngs are being loaded at all. My best guess is that your path is probably pointing to the wrong folder.

Comment: they are being loaded, it's just not creating the skybox. Anyway, I have solved this question with Nicks answer so it's all well, thank you